# Android MVVM - How to reference Activity in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

MVVM architecture,

this is my View (Activity):

```
private MyApp app;
private MainActivityVM viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
app = (MyApp) this.getApplication();
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

MainActivityVM.Factory factory = new MainActivityVM.Factory(app);

final MainActivityVM model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
.get(MainActivityVM.class);

viewModel = model;
binding.setVm(viewModel);
viewModel.onCreate();
```

and View Model:

```
public class MainActivityVM extends AndroidViewModel implements ViewModel {

    public MainActivityVM(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    @Override public void onCreate() {
         model = new MyService();
         model.getData(); /* <-- how do i pass the activity here? */
    }

    @Override public void onPause() { }

    @Override public void onResume() { }

    @Override public void onDestroy() { }

    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

        @NonNull
        private final Application mApplication;

        public Factory(@NonNull Application application) {
            mApplication = application;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            return (T) new MainActivityVM(mApplication);
        }
    }
}
```

and Model:

```
public class myService{

    public getData(){
        if(permissionacquired(){
            getdata()
        }else{
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        PermissionKey permKey = new PermissionKey(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, PermissionType.READ);
        HealthPermissionManager pmsManager = new HealthPermissionManager(mStore);
        try {
            // Show user permission UI for allowing user to change options

            /* BELOW CODE REQUIRE Activity reference to PASS */

            pmsManager.requestPermissions(Collections.singleton(permKey), MainActivity.this).setResultListener(result -> {

            /* ABOVE CODE REQUIRE Activity reference to PASS */

            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Permission callback is received.");
            Map<PermissionKey, Boolean> resultMap = result.getResultMap();

                if (resultMap.containsValue(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                    updateStepCountView("");
                    showPermissionAlarmDialog();
                } else {
                    // Get the current step count and display it
                    mReporter.start(mStepCountObserver);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(APP_TAG, "Permission setting fails.", e); }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** if you see my request permission in my Model, the API require activity to be pass - how can i pass activity reference to the request permission?

I have a get permission method that comes from Model. this get permission method from my service provider require activity e.g. `requestPermission(Activity)`

so in my ModelView, i have the model object which is the dataService from another source.

then, how I can reference Activity in my ViewModel so I can call: `model.requestPermission(Activity);` in my ViewModel?

understanding from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) that:

> **Caution**: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any
>   class that may hold a reference to the activity context.

Comment: if u will use AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel  then u can get context of application

Comment: Why do you need the `Activity` to be passed to the service provider? If you need a `Context` just to do an API call, find a way to pass the `Context` to the provider by it's creation (use the application context). If you need the `Activity` for visible output of your response, you should receive your response in the ViewModel and pass it then to your Activity (e.g. using data binding). Post an example code, how you make and handle requests now.

Comment: Thanks, i'm not free to ppst the code, i will do it later and update my question. Posting the activity to the servive provider is the provider Api requirement (not my code) - the request permission will pop up dialogs to request permission to user, that dialog was came from 3rd party service provider.

Comment: @ArtjomKönig I have updated the question with my code

Comment: IMHO you are overengineering your app architecture. Just put your `HealthPermissionManager` stuff in the `Activity`. Try to reduce your classes to the `Activity` and the `ViewModel` only, [keep it stupid simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: That's make sense, let me try it - Thanks!

Comment: Just an idea (maybe the bad one), but if you really need to pass activity, why not to do this as parameter? In this case you have your activity,but don't have any reference in your vm.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you require permission in onCreate() method you can just move logic with permission request into the activity, and pass request result into viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also added `Activity` into `ViewModel` for permissions and strings, but it's not a good idea. When I [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464039/after-disable-permissions-from-settings-and-return-to-our-app-getting-crash/70154411) location permission in one `Fragment`, an application crashed, because it restarted, then restored `FragmentManager` with fragment stack and later started `MainActivity`. So `ViewModel` got location status too early (in constructor) and threw an exception. But when I moved getting location status to a function, then the application restarted normally.

So, using Dagger, you can write something like:

```
AppModule:
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun provideActivity(app: MainApplication): AppCompatActivity = app.mainActivity
```

In `MainApplication` hold `mainActivity` and in `MainActivity` set in `onCreate`:

```
application.mainActivity = this
```

In `onDestroy`:

```
application.mainActivity = null
```

In any `ViewModel` add:

```
class SomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val activity: Provider<AppCompatActivity>
)
```

Then use it: `activity.get().getString(R.string.some_string)`.